# How actual array and reverse of it is same in javascript

Tags: javascript

I make an array and enter [a, b, c] in it and then I reverse the array to check either both the array is now different because of reverse order and then get an answer that both the arrays are same and confused about it that on which basis both are same?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) does not create a new array. It works in place and returns the same array it has been called on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code-example explaining what Daniel Hilgarth sais

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2];

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr === arr.reverse());
console.log(arr);
```

As you can see, all you did is reverse the original array, and not get a reversed copy of it